# Query for Test plan Children

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, mtm

Is there a way in Visual Studio to query for work items by specifying the name or id of the test plan of which they're part?

I have multiple test plans in a single team project so querying on team project alone does not suffice.

---

As it's not possible to query for all tests by test plan in VS, how are test case linked at database level? 
TFS does allow execution of SQL queries using the the MS client libraries using a WorkItemStore instance.

```
$wiStore = $Collection.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore")
$workitems = $wiStore.Query("")
```

Ultimately I'm attempting to iterate all attachments contained in a test project. Right now this is achieved by retrieving all tests and their (shared) steps and listing their attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately，there is no this option in work item queries for now. [Example work item queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576358.aspx)

Can't find the association between the test plan and test suite (children). The simplest way to query all test suit childrens, you may specify the test suite parent ID {*usually =(Test Plan ID+1)}*

---

Update:

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. If you want to list all tests including the child suite as below. This can be achieved as below.
[image]

And it can't be achieved by query for work items in Visual Studio.

Comment: The collection of tests contained by TestSuites aren't listed in VS when opening test suits. How would you query to retrieve the links?

Comment: I've widened the scope of my question, a query at db level would also suffice